# How do I get classical greek to work in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support

I am using LaTeX to write academic books and papers, and I need to write some things in classical Greek. The material will be citations from authors who wrote classical Greek (the authors will, actually, be 16th century humanists). I use vim to write things in. I have found keyboard layouts, and fonts, but what I am having a lot of trouble with is getting these things to actually work: I can get Greek letters OK, but I really need the accents. I cannot find out how to type the accents, whatever I do. I am not a novice in LaTeX, but this has got me defeated. Also the documentation for this doesn't seem to fit together: there are lots of helpful things on installing languages ("language" here means system-wide abstraction) and lots of helpful things on installing fonts and keyboard layouts, but actually installing a language and a keyboard layout AND MAKING THEM COMPATIBLE WITH EACH OTHER seems to be the tricky bit.

Also (and this is a very significant gap): the only dialect of Greek you can install is called "Modern Greek". This is the *only* version of Greek that I have ever seen in these configuration dialogues. Well, ancient Greek is important to quite a lot of people.

Comment: If you write in LaTeX you should use directly the LaTeX accents, instead of relying on whatever system you are using, see for example [this answer on Tex.SteackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361071/how-can-i-get-three-diacritics-on-the-same-greek-letter). (La)TeX allows you to type much more than what your system will usually allow you to.

Comment: Short citation, quotes etc in Ancient Greek can be cobbled together here: https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/greek_ancient.htm

Comment: In Kubuntu, I have Greek (polytonic) which provides the accents. The language of course still is modern Greek, but that is irrelevant as far as the keyboard layout is concerned. Polytonic Greek was used in modern Greek until the 70's.

Answer (score 3):

If you install the `ibus-m17n` package, log out, and log in again, you'll get access to a *Greek, Ancient (...mizuochi (m17n))* input method.

Answer (score 1):

In most Greek keyboards you use the right side <kbd>Alt</kbd> + "`alphanumeric key`", and for some characters right <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + "`alphanumeric key`"...

**NB:** Keep in mind that it is the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and not the left one.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Settings, region and language, add an input source, click on Modern Greek, then you get the option to choose polytone.

Answer (score 0):

I run jammin jelly. I set up greek, ancient (to 1453) as an input language along with the ibus mizuochi (m17n) keyboard. My ubuntu, at least, has a little trouble with that. It cannot show me the keyboard, and caps lock does not work, holding down the shift key does. I have answers for the most common accents and breathing marks.

- a vowel with smooth breathing and an acute is vowel'/, that is, vowel-single quote-forward slash,  ἄ
- a vowel with smooth breathing and grave is vowel'?, for example, ἂ (and instead of single quote, you can use v)
- a vowel with circumflex accent is vowel-back slash, for example ῦ (although here it looks like a tilde, but not in libre-office, at least)
- a vowel with grave accent is vowel?, for example ὰ
- a vowel with rough breathing is vowelV, for example ἁ
- a vowel with rough breathing and acute is vowelV/, for example, ἅ
- a vowel with rough breathing and grave is vowelV?, for example, ἃ

I don't know how an iota subscript is supposed to be done, but it can be done in the polytonic greek keyboard with ]vowel, for example, ᾳ

Notice that in this last example, the diacritic key comes first, but in all the others, that is, while using the ancient greek keyboard, the vowel comes first. Also, you don't need to type fast, nor do the keys need to be held down at the same time.

If anyone knows how to do iota subscript, I'm all ears.